# Watchdog and autologin - raspberry pi zero-

Tags: pi-zero, reboot, watchdog

Hi I have turned on watchdog and configurate them at my raspberry. I tested at my raspberry with fork-bomb and watchdog work - fork-bomb

```
( I wrote this command to console )
:(){ :|:& };:
```

freeze my computer and watchdog restart device. But after restart my raspberry pi zero want to write password... Anybody has idea why?

EDIT: I should write that before - if in normal situation I do `sudo reboot` or restart with, i don't need write login

EDIT2: my watchdog service : /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service
( i haven't changed it )

```
[Unit]
Description=watchdog daemon
Conflicts=wd_keepalive.service
After=multi-user.target
OnFailure=wd_keepalive.service

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/watchdog
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ -z "${watchdog_module}" ] || [ "${watchdog_module}" = "none" ] || /sbin/modprobe $watchdog_module'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '[ $run_watchdog != 1 ] || exec /usr/sbin/watchdog $watchdog_options'
ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c '[ $run_wd_keepalive != 1 ] || false'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Pretty sure that will amount to an unclean shutdown; the forkbomb would have prevented anything else -- I've never used the watchdog, and don't know whether it even tries to do such, but if it does it would fail.   While the system wouldn't have been doing much I/O to the SD card at the time, reducing the chance of filesystem corruption, it could still happen.

Comment: If you boot normally, do you get asked for a password?

Comment: @JaromandaX - if i boote normally (for example `sudo reboot`) after restart i don't need write a password

Comment: @goldilocks - hmm okay - so if it could be problem with forkbomk what i should use to test of my watchdog work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want that your raspberry reboots without a password prompt / autologin enabled?
This can be done in raspi-config `1 System Options`--> `S5 Boot / Auto Login` then select `Console Autologin` or `Desktop Autologin`.

Comment: Exacly - autologin/without a password prompt is my purpose. In normal situation after restart with gui or `sudo reboot` Normally computer is run and I will be autologged - but when i force raspberry to use watchdog - after restart i need write a pass

Comment: Can you please post the code of your watchdog?

Comment: do you mean a watchdog.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i found answer at this page (and this worked for fork-bomb case)

https://medium.com/@arslion/enabling-watchdog-on-raspberry-pi-b7e574dcba6b

I changed in last line
from

```
WantedBy=default.target
```

to

```
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and ofcourse - i did `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` in CLI to refresh implement this change to service

Thanks everybody for comments